# C++のアドレスとポインタについて

Tags: c++

```
int number = 10
int *var = &number;
cout << *var << endl;
```

上記コードにおいて、numberのアドレスが出力されると思っておりましたが、
10が出力されます。

一方、

```
int number = 10
int *var = &number;
cout << var << endl;
```

上記コードでは、10が出力されると思っておりましたが、numberのアドレスが出力されます。
なぜこのようになるのかご教示頂けますと幸いです。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

今回のプログラムにおいて、ポインタ変数の名前は `*var` ではなく `var` であることに注意してください。

```
int number = 10
int *var = &number;
```

ここまで書いた時点で、それぞれの変数はこういうことになっています。

- `number`： `int` 型の変数で、値は `10`。
- `var`： `int *` 型の変数で、値は `number` のアドレス。つまり、「`int` 型の変数 `number`」へのポインタ。

ここで、今回のプログラムに登場する `*` には2種類あることを注意しておきます。1つは型の名前に登場し、ポインタを表す `*`。そしてもう1つは、単項演算子としての `*` です。単項演算子 `*` は、「そのアドレスにある値」を求めるために使います。したがって、

- `var` を評価すると `number` のアドレス
- `*var` を評価すると `number` の値

が得られることになります。

Comment: 詳細な説明いつもありがとうございます。単項演算子 * は、「そのアドレスにある値」を求めるために使うという点を恥ずかしながら初めて知りました。引き続きどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3):

なぜ・・・って「仕様です」

宣言 `int *var;` の読み方ですが、「宣言以外の場所、すなわち、変数を使う場所で `*var` と書いたら `int` になります」。だから `var` とだけ書いたら `int` ではなくてポインタです。理屈通りの挙動をちゃんと示しているでしょ。

Comment: 説明ありがとうございました。簡単な質問でお手間をわずらわせてしまい失礼いたしました。